# How to find a eigenvectors with respect to the given matrix and how to find a diagonalizer.

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I got this question and cannot solve part (ii) and (iii). I'd like a solution, since it's been a while since I've had Linear Algebra. I do not know how to find the eigenvectors with respect to this matrix and I do not know how to find the diagonalizer. Never understood the latter. Can someone help me ASAP? I've got a test coming. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Once again, please don’t include critical parts of your question as images. They’re not searchable and are inaccessible to people using screen readers. If you’re not going to take your own time to post questions that are up to the standards of this site (see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992)), why do you expect others here to take their time to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvectors are given by
$$
\ker(A-\lambda I)
$$
where $\lambda$ stands for the eigenvalues you found in part 1. Finding the vectors that span the above kernel is finding the eigenvector.

In order to be diagonalizable, you need three linearly independent eigenvectors. The diagonalizer will be a 3 by 3 matrix made up of these vectors.

Comment: The OP should verify that the diagonalizer diagonalizes the original matrix!